# trying to update a span with maths result in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

I am having what is probably a simple issue with some jQuery code.  I have two inputs that form variables to a simple piece of maths.  One is a text box, the other a range input.  I need to display the result of a very simple calculation in a span element.

Here is the html and js I have:

```
<input type="text" name="txt_bserves" id="txt_bserves" value="0">
<span id="currsalesval">10%</span>
<input type="range" name="convertslider" id="convertslider" min="0" max="100" value="10">
<span id="currsalesconv">525 serves</span>

function updateValue()
{
  var sliderval = $('#convertslider').val();
  var bserves = $("#txt_bserves").val();
  var cserves = (bserves * (sliderval/100));
  $("#currsalesval").text(sliderval.concat("%"));
  $("#currsalesconv").text(cserves.concat(" serves"));
}

$('#convertslider').on('change, mousemove', function(){
  updateValue();
});
```

The issue comes on the third line, a simple piece of maths to calculate a percentage of the input box.

The currsalesval span updates fine with the percentage value from the slider.  But the currsalesval span is not updated with the cserve value.

I realise this might be a type conversion issue, but having been thrugh a number of different variations of conversions, I thought I'd ask here instead.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Have you tried `cserves.toString().concat(" serves")`?

Comment: I can't believe I missed that one.  Feel so stupid.   Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cserves is not a string , so it doesn't have a concat method. Instead of :

```
$("#currsalesconv").text(cserves.concat(" serves"));
```

try

```
$("#currsalesconv").text(cserves + " serves");
```